# I can't setup my enviroment to connect my consumer to docker kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, kafka-python

I've tried to create a Python Consumer for kafka running on Docker. I've read about kafka listeners but still not getting the right setup. I'm new at Docker and also to kafka.

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: debezium/zookeeper:1.1
    ports:
     - 2181:2181
     - 2888:2888
     - 3888:3888
  kafka:
    image: debezium/kafka:1.1
    ports:
     - 9092:9092
    links:
     - zookeeper
    environment:
     - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
  mysql:
    image: debezium/example-mysql:1.1
    ports:
     - 3306:3306
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debezium
     - MYSQL_USER=mysqluser
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw
  connect:
    image: debezium/connect:1.1
    ports:
     - 8083:8083
    links:
     - kafka
     - mysql
    environment:
     - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
     - GROUP_ID=1
     - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
     - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
     - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses
```

Following the steps the debezium tutorial I can get the topics but not the messages using this code on Python.

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'dbserver1.inventory.customers',
     bootstrap_servers=['192.168.99.100:9092'],
     auto_offset_reset='earliest',
     enable_auto_commit=True,
     group_id='1',
     value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

print(consumer.topics())

for m in consumer:
    print(m)
```

Comment: Where is your Python code running? Docker, or local to the Docker host?

Comment: What do you exactly want? Just read messages from dbserver1.inventory.customers topic?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt My Python Code is on my docker host.

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander Yes, I'm just trying to read the messages from that topic.

Comment: You are using the same `group_id` for Kafka Connect and for consumer. Try to change it (maybe just set `group_id=None`)

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander I already did it and nothing changed. I've read that it has something to do with Listeners but I'm not quite sure how to use them

Comment: Did you change group_id for consumer, right?

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander Yes, I only changed the Id for the consumer

Comment: Maybe your topic is empty

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander I'm using a mysql connector and when I create a consumer on my kafka image, I can see the messages on that topic.